# Does going faster always result in more calories burnt

Tags: speed, exercise

Say the same 5mile ride going at 5 miles per hour versus 10, 15 20 etc.  Even though the faster speed means shorter ride does it also always result in more calories burned?

I have the same commute looking to up the exercise somehow.

Comment: Next question is where do those calories come from, and is it the right source for your exercise goal? There is solid science behind need for a lot of  low/medium effort, long distance training. Often the best way to up the exercise is simply take the long way.

Comment: @mattnz: I’d assume that for a given distance, riding it at higher intensity (i.e. faster) will always result in more “gains”. Of course the question is if it’s appropriate from a training volume and injury risk point of view.

Comment: Have you ever driven a car and had to refuel?

Comment: Is walking an option ?

Comment: @Michael speed is not the same thing as intensity.  there are other factors like wind.

Answer (score 10):

All other things being equal, yes. The increase in effort more than makes up for the decrease in ride time.

Consider two scenarios where one rides 20 km: first at 25 km/h, second at 30 km/h. In the first case, riding at 25 km/h takes 96 W of power, in the second, riding at 30 km/h takes 150 W according to [this web page](https://www.gribble.org/cycling/power_v_speed.html) (using my own stats).

```
 96 W * 20 km / 25 km/h = 276 kJ over 48 minutes  
150 W * 20 km / 30 km/h = 360 kJ over 40 minutes
```

Thanks to a lucky mathematical coincidence, kilojoules of work is almost exactly equal to calories burned. Some estimating tools treat calories burned as 10% above kJ of work.

Comment: But going faster does not (necessarily) imply burning more calories.  One can go faster because they are in an aerodynamic "tuck" that lets them burn fewer calories.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Right. Which is why I led off with "All other things being equal…"

Comment: "Thanks to a lucky mathematical coincidence, kilojoules of work is almost exactly equal to [kilo]calories burned" Do you have more info about this claim? There's a factor 4.18 between a cal and a Joule. Do you consider the human efficiency to be ~25%?

Comment: @EricDuminil 25% is not precise but it's close enough to be useful.

Answer (score 10):

Speaking purely in calories and power, this is just a small elaboration on Adam's answer: the power required to maintain a certain speed against aerodynamic drag is proportionate to the *cube* of that speed. The time to complete a distance is inversely proportional to speed. Thus, you will always burn more total calories if you increase your speed. The fact I asserted about power and aerodynamic drag is available in the calculator that Adam [linked](https://www.gribble.org/cycling/power_v_speed.html).

I am oversimplifying a bit, since I'm ignoring elevation change and rolling resistance. The power to overcome rolling resistance (that is the power consumed to overcome the friction between tires and ground) is [linearly proportional to your speed](https://www.trainingpeaks.com/blog/understanding-rolling-resistance/). However, I believe that the speed where aerodynamic drag is greater than rolling resistance is quite low, possibly in the region of 10mph. Whatever the case, the total power required to hold a certain speed does not increase linearly, thus giving you your answer.